# (MYSQL] Use an "CASE ... WHEN" alias in a date_add function

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Can I use an alias create with the "CASE ... WHEN" (delayDate), in another function, like date_add() :

doctrine way :

```
->addSelect("CASE c.time
                        WHEN '24' then 1
                        WHEN '48' then 2
                        WHEN '72' then 3
                        WHEN '96' then 4
                        ELSE 0
                       END
                        as delayDate ,
                    date_add(CURRENT_DATE(), delayDate, 'DAY') as firstDateDelivery")
```

This because I **can't** use 'HOUR' in doctrine with the date_add() function.

I think, in "pure" mysql, it's not working anymore...

Can you help me please ?
F.

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quote from `DAY`, and check this `DATE_ADD()` usage [func_date_add](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp).

```
->addSelect("CASE c.time
                        WHEN '24' then 1
                        WHEN '48' then 2
                        WHEN '72' then 3
                        WHEN '96' then 4
                        ELSE 0
                       END
                        as delayDate ,
              CASE c.time
                        WHEN '24' then date_add(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                        WHEN '48' then date_add(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
                        WHEN '72' then date_add(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
                        WHEN '96' then date_add(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)
                        ELSE CURRENT_DATE()
                       END
                        as firstDateDelivery")
```

Comment: Thanks :), but I've this error : QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 382: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_COMMA, got '1'

Comment: And using this : WHEN '24' then date_add(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL, 1, DAY). It's not working too. The error : [Syntax Error] line 0, col 383: Error: Expected StateFieldPathExpression | string | InputParameter | FunctionsReturningStrings | AggregateExpression, got '1'